# Should "a/an" articles be used before general concepts?

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

Let me give you some examples from my textbook, that were confusing for me.

1. How many strings does ___ bass guitar have?
2. How many players can be on court in ___ basketball team?
3. Which European country hasn't fought in ___ war since 1815?
4. Is __ spider ___ insect?

I "feel" that they can be spoken in either way, i.e. with article or without, but I'm not sure.

And by general concept I mean some class of common objects, like biology taxon... Now, when I've mentioned it, I'm starting to think that taxons cannot be singular words.

In these examples I can consider guitar, team, war, spider and insect as objects in general or as some "one" object. It's hard to explain, but I think it's an influence of my native language and Japanese. I suppose, any singular countable noun in English should be preceded by an article (or other specifying word). And general entities should be used in a plural form. Please, correct my conclusions if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify what "either way" refers to?  What are you comparing *a(n)* with?

Comment: What do mean by "general concepts"? 1, 2 and 4 don't seem to qualify as such.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I've tried to correct my question.

Comment: For what it's worth, #2 is a poorly-worded sentence, even when the article is correctly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them take the article. The exception is “*fought in ___ war*”, which can be *fought in a war* or *fought in war*.

The reason for this is that the word *war* means both the event (as in “*another war has started*”) as well as the state/practice (as in “*war has claimed many lives*”). However, in this specific construct, *fought in a war* is more common.

Comment: Interestingly enough, though (and perhaps one reason this can be difficult for a learner), the article would be omitted in Nos. 1 & 4 if the object was pluralized: _How many strings do bass guitars have? Are spiders insects?_